# What is the PowerShell syntax to capture a named group from a [regex] type accelerator expression?

Tags: .net, regex, powershell, type-accelerators

The question uses the following sample string:

```
$r = 
"20160112 11:26:39 UPDATE CMIS-NC.ABC.LA012345J.NAM/MOUSE, MICKEY J.SEX/M.RAC/W.DOB/19670601.PCA/A1.ARI/CRIM1234567.DNY/CONVICTED OF DISTRIBUTING THE PEACE.OCA/123456.SOR/LA.MIS/CONFIRM RECORD AT DISNEY STUDIOS 123-456-7890 OR PAGER 123-456-7890.
20160112 11:26:39 RESPONSE CMIS-NC.ACK 1234567890 CMIS-NC  123456 CMIS-NC  123456 20160112 11:26:31

.
20160112 11:26:39 INFO MSN of message to LEMS is <1234567890>.
20160112 11:26:39 RESPONSE CMIS-NC.MSG 1234567890 CMIS-NC  123456 NC2K     AC1234 20160112 11:26:31
LA012345J
CTL/
ATN/

6L12345678901234567890EDP 
LA012345J
ACCEPT MKE/EDP
NAM//MOUSE, MICKEY J
ARI/CRIM1234567
NRI/1234567890"
```

A named group can be captured using the PowerShell built-in regular expression, by referencing them in the `$matches` automatic variable:

```
$updateRequestPattern = "(?<RequestDate>\d{8} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) (?<UpdateRequest>UPDATE CMIS-NC\.[A-Z]{3,4}\.LA012345J\..+)\n"

$request = $r -match $updateRequestPattern

$matches['RequestDate']
```

But what if I instead want to use the `[regex]` type accelerator?

There, the `$matches` automatic variable won't work. Neither can I do something like `[regex]::Groups['RequestDate'].Value` (which produces a "Cannot index into a null array." error).

Can anyone complete this example (or offer another example) to capture named groups (and thus show how other .NET `[regex]` methods can be exposed)?

```
$updateRequestPattern = "(?<RequestDate>\d{8} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) (?<UpdateRequest>UPDATE CMIS-NC\.[A-Z]{3,4}\.LA036035J\..+)\n"
$request = [regex]::Matches($r, $updateRequestPattern)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The return value is a MatchCollection, so you can index into that, then refer to the groups property, and use the indexing the same way from there:

```
$request[0].Groups['RequestDate']
```

Comment: Possibly on the right track, however, this generates the "cannot index into a null array" error.

Comment: Well, your example regex won't match anything in the input string you gave. It's the `LA...J` part that doesn't match. Try `LA\d+J` just for purposes of demonstrating this.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not seeing that the pattern doesn't match (it matches in Regex101.com, and it matched in the first example that I provided).

But following your suggestion, and simplifying even further, then, this works as you recommended.

```
$s = "ABC123"
$p = "(?<LetterPart>[A-Z]+)(?<NumberPart>\d+)"
$result = [regex]::Matches($s, $p)

$result[0].Groups['LetterPart'].Value
$result[0].Groups['NumberPart'].Value
```

Thank you!