# ReGex improvement AssemblyVersion.cs

Tags: c#, powershell

I would like to improve the RegEx for or my Substring ()
I need to recover the version number of my assembly.cs what I happen at the moment, but with just a 7 carateres number.

my problem is that the assembly version is likely to be 12 or 13 chars, and my return value will be truncated, and that's not what I want.

Actual Assembly:

```
  [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

i return the good version:

```
  1.0.0.0
```

But in futur AssemblyVersion will be like this:

```
  [assembly: AssemblyVersion("3.54.24.128")]
```

And here i return:

```
  3.54.24
```

I expected this value independing number of caractere:

```
  3.54.24.128 or 1.0.0.0
```

Can you find a solution on the Regex and the Substring () or maybe a best partice for this case.

I also can't escape the end [''] and [)] of my assemblyVersion

Here's what I did:

```
$path = "C:\Users\Documents\Temp\AssemblyInfo-test.cs"

$assemblyFileContent = Get-Content -Path $path

# Selects the line corresponding to the pattern, which styles the assembly version
$assemblyLinePattern = Select-String -Path $path -Pattern '^\[assembly: AssemblyVersion\("(.*)"\)\]' -CaseSensitive

# Extrat the version of "assemblyInfo.cs"
$assemblyVersion = $assemblyLinePattern.Line.Substring(28,7)

# Stores the assembly version in a custom variable "custom.AssemblyVersion" in the next pipeline CI task.
$assemblyVersion
```

Comment: Please pay attention when selecting tags! By mistake you selected the C language tag instead of C# (which I assumed you meant to use).

Comment: My bad, i am sorry.

Comment: Maybe `[version]$assemblyVersion = $assemblyLinePattern.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value`, then `$assemblyVersion.ToString()`?  That way you can capture the `Major`, `Minor`, `Build`, and `Revision` numbers in separate properties of `$assemblyVersion`.  Worth a mention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `Substring` here. [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7) allows you to see the groups in your matches. Please try this:

```bsh
$AssemblyPath = "C:\Users\Documents\Temp\AssemblyInfo-test.cs"
$AssemblyContent = $assemblyFileContent = Get-Content -Path $AssemblyPath
$AssemblyMatches = $AssemblyContent | Select-String -Pattern "^\[assembly: AssemblyVersion\(`"(.*)`"\)\]" -CaseSensitive
$AssemblyMatches.Matches.Groups[1].Value
```

You could even [name the capture group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37355076/what-is-the-powershell-syntax-to-capture-a-named-group-from-a-regex-type-accel) so you do not have to refer it as `Groups[1]`.